# Magento 2 sitemap wrong paths in sitemap index when running on cron

Tags: magento2.2.2, sitemaps

I am using Magento 2.2.2.
Please see below the current settings of the sitemap.
[image: wrong sitemap base path]

It works correctly when we create sitemap by hitting generate button in admin. But when it gets generated automatically using cron it shows /public_html/ in sitemap index for sub-sitemaps, please see below image, its sitemap.xml

[image: wrong sitemap base path]
Thank you

Comment: I'm also getting the error, but couldn't resolve using the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.
Its not recommended but you can try it as temporary fix. Override below file.
Magento_Root/vendor/magento/module-sitemap/model/sitemap.php
comment line 705
// return realpath($this->_request->getServer('DOCUMENT_ROOT'));
And add your own domain directly.
return 'https://www.example.com';

Working for now.